# STL Priority queue of struct not correctly working

Tags: c++, struct, stl, priority-queue

I'm having a problem while trying to put structs in a priority queue, it is not correctly organizing by the score as shown in the image below, it should be organized by the biggest number.

Minimal code:

```
Class foo{
        public:
        foo();
        // this is in the .h file
        struct individuo{
            individuo(){}
            individuo(QColor cor): gene(cor){}
            QColor gene;
            int score;
            int probabilidade;
            int epoca;
        };

        // this is in the .h file
        struct Comparador{
          bool operator()(const individuo* arg1,const individuo* arg2) const {
            return arg1->score < arg2->score;
          }
        };
        void function();
        priority_queue<individuo *,vector<individuo *>, Comparador> individuos;
};

    void foo::function(){
            individuo *a = new individuo(QColor(r,g,b));
            a->score = rand() % 255;
            individuos.push(a);
    }
```

and here its how it gets organized in memory:

[image: memory]

it's possible to see that the structs are not being correctly organized by its score, why?

Comment: Your example is certainly minimal, but it is far from being complete, and is not verifiable. Please edit your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: `priority_queue` doesn't keep the container sorted. It only guarantees that the element at the front is the largest one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i quickly fixed the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the `individuo struct` to be sorted by the score, use std::map with the score as the key. priority_queue is used for a different purpose.

> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides constant time lookup of the largest (by default) element, at the expense of logarithmic insertion and extraction.

EDIT: Alternatively, just put the struct in a `std::vector` or an `std::array` and use `std::sort` on it.

Comment: Another equally useful option you have, is `std::set` if you don't want to go after a key value pair.

Comment: map and set require unique values, ill use multimap, but thanks

Comment: How about a `std::multiset` then?

Answer (score 0):

A priority queue does not have an interface to iterate over the elements for a reason, it is not relevant to the core service it provides. And masking an implementation allows more efficient choices.

A `std::priority_queue` only exposes `push/pop/top`, it is possible because of that to implement it with a heap. It could be rewrite easiely with `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap` over `std::vector` and does not have a need to maintain a fully ordered list of elements to provide the service.